# Tangent plane to the graph of $f(x,y)=|xy|$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Given the function $$f(x,y)=|xy|$$
how to know if the graph of f has a tangent plane at $(0,0)$?

I know that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ don't exist at $(0,0)$, is this enough to say that the tangent plane doesn't exist at that point?

My intuition says that maybe a tangent plane could exist since both axis are in the graph.

Comment: Why do you think the partial derivatives don't exist at $(0,0)$? You have $f(x,0)=f(0,y)=0$, for all $x$ and all $y$. Can't you differentiate $0$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By linearization we have that the tangent plane at $p = (a,b,f(a,b))$ is given by;

$$z = f(a,b) + (x-a)f_x(p) + (y-b) f_y(p)$$

i.e you have $\langle f_x(p), f_y(p), -1 \rangle \cdot \langle x-a,y-b,z-f(a,b)\rangle = 0$ i.e $\langle f_x(p),f_y(p), -1 \rangle$ is the normal vector for the plane at $p$.

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(t,0) - f(0,0)}{t} = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(0,t) - f(0,0)}{t} = 0$$

Comment: That I won't be able to find a normal vector so therefore no tangent plane?

Comment: Thank you, I was having trouble because I draw the graph and thought for a second that it definitely has a tangent plane at (0,0).

Comment: My question is, how did you determine that the partials didn't exist? They actually do and are zero, so the tangent plane is $z = 0$. Use the limit definition.

Comment: if $x=0$ then $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0+h,y_0)-f(0,y_0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\mid h\mid}{h}$, which doesn't exist. So the partial derivative with respect to $x$ doesn't exist if $x=0$.

Comment: If $y=0$ then the partial derivative with respect to $y$ won't exist.

Comment: $f(0+h,0) = f(h,0)$ which by definition of your function you have $f(h,0) = |h \cdot 0| = 0$ i.e in the numerator you have $0$ and so the limit is zero.

Comment: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\mid (x+h)y\mid- \mid xy \mid}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\mid y\mid \frac {\mid x+h\mid-\mid x\mid}{h}$. Isn't there a problem at $x=0$?

Comment: Remember you are plugging in $x = y  = 0$. So you have $|y| = 0$.

Comment: I think I see now, so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ doesn't exist if $x=0$ and $y\neq 0$, and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ doesn't exist if $y=0$ and $x\neq 0$, but if $x=0$ AND $y=0$ then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$?

Comment: And so the graph has a tangent plane at $(0,0)$ whose equation is $z=0$

Comment: Yup. It looks like you have it now.

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me where my mistake was. Now the answer matches my intuition.

Comment: No problem. If everything is done and you are please, you can accept the answer to close the question.

Comment: Bit if the partials exist at that point and the limit of the absolut value over the norm is zero then the tangent plane exists?

Comment: @416333: Yes, I just realized that my comment was completely wrong, so I deleted it. The function *is* in fact differentiable at the origin, contrary to what I said before. But I still think that it needs to be *motivated*; it's not completely obvious, because of the absolute value signs.

Comment: Yes, completely. I'll write a complete answer later today with a formal proof. It's good to know that intuition is good though, and that the function has indeed a tangent plane at $(0,0)$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, $$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(x,y)}=\lim_{h\to\infty} \frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}=\lim_{h\to\infty} \frac {| (x+h)(y)|- |xy|}{h}=\lim_{h\to\infty} |y| \frac{|x+h|-|x|}{h}$$
It follows that  $$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(0,0)}=\lim_{h\to\infty} |0| \frac{|0+h|-|0|}{h}=\lim_{h\to\infty} |0| \frac{|h|}{h}=0$$

Also, $$\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg|_{(x,y)}=\lim_{h\to\infty} \frac{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)}{h}=\lim_{h\to\infty} \frac {| (x)(y+h)|- |xy|}{h}=\lim_{h\to\infty} |x| \frac{|y+h|-|y|}{h}$$

so $$\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg|_{(0,0)}=\lim_{h\to\infty} |0| \frac{|0+h|-|0|}{h}=\lim_{h\to\infty} |0| \frac{|h|}{h}=0$$

This means that both $$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(0,0)}$$ and $$\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg|_{(0,0)}$$ exist.

It remains to show that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(0,0)}(x-0)-\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg|_{(0,0)}(y-0)}{\|(x,y)\|}=0$$

But $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(0,0)}(x-0)-\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg|_{(0,0)}(y-0)}{\|(x,y)\|}$$ $$=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)}{\|(x,y)\|}$$ $$=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{|xy|}{\|(x,y)\|}$$ $$=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$$.

So with all this we can conclude that that $f$ has a tangent plane at $(0,0)$